# How do I create a Navigation Bar in Xamarin Forms for iOS?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Is there support in XAML in Xamarin Forms for creating a Navigation Bar for iOS? I searched in all Xamarin support, forums and internet..

At this point I am not convinced that there is support but I really don't want to re-invent the wheel if it's already invented..

---

*Edit*:

By navigation bar I mean this thingie:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you create your pages using `NavigationPage`, Xamarin.Forms automatically creates a navigation bar on iOS. You can also modify quite a few things of the navigation bar, like this:

```
NavigationPage.SetBackButtonTitle(this, ""); // Empty text
NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, false); // No back button
NavigationPage.SetTitleIcon (this, someIcon); // Set the icon
```

Take a look at the following article for quite a good explanation of differences between ContentPage and NavigationPage: [Xamarin.Forms Pages: ContentPage and NavigationPage](http://www.pauloortins.com/2015/04/12/xamarin-forms-pages-contentpage-navigationpage/)

Xamarin's official documentation also covers the navigation quite well: [Hierarchial Navigation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/hierarchical/)

---

Have you set your root page to be of type `NavigationPage`? In your `App` class you should have something like

```
MainPage = new ContentPage(); // etc.
```

Change it to be something like this

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FirstPageOfTheApp());
//FirstPageOfTheApp should be of type ContentPage.
```

So to sum it up, the root page needs to be `NavigationPage` and all the other pages of type `ContentPage`.

Comment: I've tried to set this properties in App.xaml.cs and in Page.xaml.cs without any effect. I have a fresh Xamarin.Forms created, I run it, it has no Navigation Bar: http://imgur.com/a/FLpXG

Comment: Have you set your root page to be of type NavigationPage? In your App class you should have something like `MainPage = new ContentPage` etc. Change it to be something like this: `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new FirstPageOfTheApp());` FirstPageOfTheApp should be of type ContentPage. So to sum it up, the root page needs to be NavigationPage and all the other pages of type ContentPage. I hope that this helps.

Comment: Wow, that seems to be it! I changed in App.xaml.cs as you said and it now shows the back button! (Not at first, only after the first change of page but I guess that is the way it should) :)    THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome! It's a small change in code but the results are quite nice. :)